# In Jenkins, View Job Filters plugin, how do you use a Regular Expression Job Filter on SCM Configuration to filter on a branch name?

Tags: git, plugins, jenkins, build

I'm trying to create a view in Jenkins filtered on the same branch name existing in multiple jobs.
I have looked through the View Job Filters documentation and I can see where it says it can be done... but no examples on how to accomplish it.

I have downloaded the View Job Filters plugin and in the configuration I have put

```
\.\*branch1.\*  in the regular expression text field.  
'Job SCM Configuration' in the Match Value.  
'Include Matched' in the Match Type
```

I have branches with that name but no Jobs are showing up in the view.

[Link to View Job Filters Documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/View+Job+Filters#ViewJobFilters-RegularExpressionJobFilter)

Answer (score 1):

The only part involving branch name filtering is in [issue JENKINS-6932](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-6932), and the release note says:

> #### Version 1.1
>
> Fixed JENKINS-6932 - "Allow to filter by SCM Branch" - **applies to CVS only**

So that wouldn't work for Git.